# Android Starting an Activity Introduction - Defining text_message

Tags: android

I am working on the Android guide here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html and there is reference to a variable that has never been created

```
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_message);
```

Where am I supposed to define text_message?

Thanks for your help!

**Update**: I believe the chunk of code from which this is taken is merely an example, and not to be incorporated with the application we created in the previous part of the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is declared here

```
TextView mTextView; // Member variable for text view in the layout  // Right here

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Declaring it outside of a method, generally right after class declaration, makes it a member variable so it can be used anywhere in the class, including inner classes and listeners. You just can't initialize it in the same place because you haven't `inflated` your `Layout` yet by calling `setContentView()`

**Short example**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView mTextView; // Member variable for text view in the layout

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set the user interface layout for this Activity
    // The layout file is defined in the project res/layout/main_activity.xml file
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // Initialize member TextView so we can manipulate it later
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_message);   // findViewById) looks for the id you set in the xml file, here text_message
}
```

`R.id.text_message` is defined in the `main_activity.xml` which could look something like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_message"   <!-- this is where the R.id.text_message comes from -->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

That documentation is definitely good to go through but you may want to start [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) and go through a short example starting from creating a project

Comment: You might also want to show where the `findViewById()` goes as well as wrap everything in an example Activity class to show the full syntax (including all closing braces needed for this to compile.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I was unclear, I am updating my question. The R.id.text_message has never been defined anywhere. Looking back at the tutorial it appears that the code they show is simply an example and not to be incorporated with I already have.

Comment: @Code-Guru that's what the tutorials are for. But I can edit if there is more confusion

Comment: @jsc123 I have edited with a short example. Let me know if that doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

use this way define the xml layout inside the folder of res/layout/main.xml and set in setconentView.

```
private TextView mTextView = null; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    stContentView(R.layout.main);
mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_message);
mTextView.setText("Hello");
}
```